# How to concat 2 lambda result in an array

Tags: javascript

I'm doing 2 HTTP request to have 2 different sets of data.
Both sets have user information.

I use lambda to extact the information :

Set 1 :

```
$scope.snapi.datas.employees.listc =
    $scope.snapi.datas.changes.changes.map( function(val) {
        return val.assignedTo.display_value;
    })
    .filter((value, index, self) => self.indexOf(value) === index);
```

Set 2 :

```
$scope.snapi.datas.employees.listi =
    $scope.snapi.datas.incidents.incidents.map( function(val) {
        return val.assignedTo.display_value;
    })
    .filter((value, index, self) => self.indexOf(value) === index);
```

I would like to aggregate the result to display it ( using angular-js)

Code angular :

```
<tr ng-repeat="emp in snapi.datas.employees.list">
    <td> {{emp}}
</tr>
```

I can display one of the other but not both

Code :

```
if ( $scope.snapi.filter.tableIncident && $scope.snapi.filter.tableChange ){
    $scope.snapi.datas.employees.list =
        $scope.snapi.datas.employees.listc
            .push($scope.snapi.datas.employees.listi);
}
```

But this is the result i got :

[image: THe data from listc is ok, but nmot the data from listi]

Do you have any why ?

Thanks,
Nicolas

Answer (score 0):

Use concat() rather than push() to combine the lists:

```
$scope.snapi.datas.employees.list = 
  $scope.snapi.datas.employees.listc
    .concat($scope.snapi.datas.employees.listi);
```

Comment: It's not working .. the 2 tables are not being concatenated.

Comment: If `$scope.snapi.datas.employees.listc` and `$scope.snapi.datas.employees.listi` are arrays, the `concat` call should return a new array containing the concatenation of the two arrays.  The `push` in your code will not concatenate the lists, but will nest the second list at the end of the first list, and will return the length of the resulting list rather than the list itself.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was with AngularJS,  which wouldn't display the list after the concat.

After this change it worked : add **track by $index**

```
<tr ng-repeat="emp in snapi.datas.employees.list track by $index">
    <td> {{emp}}
</tr>
```